# You Won't Believe The Solution To This Insane Riley!

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> If you're using my prefix, you're probably a developer or Hollywood "Hacker,"
>   Or perhaps just opposed to things that sound too sticky.
>
> If you're on my suffix, you're surrounded by water without much to stand on,
>   And quite possibly near (or in!) the Old Smoke.
>
> If you're at my infix, you're arriving or departing a state without a directional pair,
>   At a port that is near a jewel in the hills.
>
> All parts of me are the same length, though all take different forms.
>   One's a word, one's an initialism, and one's a code, but not necessarily in that order.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are

> **CLICKBAIT**

If you're using my prefix, you're probably a developer or Hollywood "Hacker,"
Or perhaps just opposed to things that sound too sticky.

> This is **CLI**, short for Command Line Interface, which is a developer tool. You would use this if you are opposed to a Graphical User Interface, or GUI (pronounced "goo-ey").

If you're on my suffix, you're surrounded by water without much to stand on,
And quite possibly near (or in!) the Old Smoke.

> This is **AIT**, which is a small island, especially used to refer to river islands found on the River Thames ("Old Smoke" is a nickname for London).

If you're at my infix, you're arriving or departing a state without a directional pair,
At a port that is near a jewel in the hills.

> This is **CKB**, the code for the North Central West Virginia Airport West Virginia has no directional pair, i.e. there's no East Virginia.  This airport services Clarksburg, WV, known as "the Jewel of the Hills".

All parts of me are the same length, though all take different forms.
One's a word, one's an initialism, and one's a code, but not necessarily in that order.

> Each is three letters. AIT is a word, CLI is an initialism, and CKB is a code.

The title refers to

> the common headline for clickbait articles, "You Won't Believe..."

Comment: Well done.  This was a headscratcher.